# How to drag and drop tabs between two containers

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have two tab containers (pannels?) each with multiple tabs. I want to be able to drag and drop one tab from container 1 to container 2.

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#sortable) you can find an jQuery UI example of single container with multiple tabs, and you can drag one tab around and drop in another position.

I want to be able to move one tab outside the container in to another container.

Just to put some code snippet as suggested:

```js
$( function() {

 var tabs1 = $( "#tabs1" ).tabs();
 tabs1.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({
  axis: "x",
  stop: function() {
   tabs1.tabs( "refresh" );
  }
 });

 var tabs2 = $( "#tabs2" ).tabs();
 tabs2.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({
  axis: "x",
  stop: function() {
   tabs2.tabs( "refresh" );
  }
 });

} );
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />


<div id="tabs1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="tabs2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use bootstrap and jQuery but might accept another solutions too.

Thanks

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: Doesn't anyone google anymore these days? Open Google, type _drag drop pure javascript_ and voila...

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Michel Are those google results working for tabs with pannels too?
I did searched on google and stackoverflow but received nothing on the subject.

Comment: @WebDevBooster I don't have any code snippet. I just tried several jQuery UI plugins but they only work for single container.
I will put some code snippet from those plugins but I don't know if it will help in anyway as I don't want specifically for that. It can be any solution.

Comment: Why have you tagged it with `bootstrap-4` if you aren't actually using Bootstrap 4? Also, I wasn't asking you to post some random code snippet. I asked you to post **YOUR** current code snippet. And if you don't have any, then your question wouldn't qualify for getting any answers (and would get closed pretty quick). That's just the rule of the land here. I didn't make those rules.

Comment: I use bootstrap-4 in my project in case that will trigger any thoughts for anybody.
Is not that random, I actually used that code in my project but did not worked as you can see, and now is deleted as I am searching for alternate solutions. I use codeigniter and that code is the only code in my template file. If someone can work on that code snippet and find a solution that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer to my own post, using jQueryUI, based on @Rohan Kumar answer.

There's only one glitch, you have to shake a little bit the moved tab so that the tabs can redraw themselves(I'll edit my answer if I'll ever find an answer for that bug).

```js
$( function() {



 var tabs1 = $( "#tabs1" ).tabs();
 tabs1.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({
  axis: "x, y",
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  stop: function() {
   tabs1.tabs( "refresh" );
  }
 }).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui) {
    var panelId = $(ui.draggable[0]).attr( "aria-controls" );
    let panel = $( "#" + panelId );
    let p1id = panel.parent().attr("id");

    let newParent = $( event.target.offsetParent );
    let p2id = newParent.attr("id");

    if(p1id !== p2id) {
     panel.attr("style", "display: none");
     panel.attr("aria-hidden", "true");
     panel.detach().appendTo(newParent);

     let tabraw = ui.draggable[0];
     let tab = $( tabraw );

     tabs1.tabs("refresh");

    }
      }
    });



 // Close icon: removing the tab on click
 tabs1.on( "click", "span.ui-icon-close", function() {
  var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
  $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
  tabs1.tabs( "refresh" );
 });



var tabs2 = $( "#tabs2" ).tabs();
 tabs2.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({
  axis: "x, y",
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  stop: function() {
   tabs2.tabs( "refresh" );
  }
 }).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui) {
    var panelId = $(ui.draggable[0]).attr( "aria-controls" );
    let panel = $( "#" + panelId );
    let p1id = panel.parent().attr("id");

    let newParent = $( event.target.offsetParent );
    let p2id = newParent.attr("id");

    if(p1id !== p2id) {
     panel.attr("style", "display: none");
     panel.attr("aria-hidden", "true");
     panel.detach().appendTo(newParent);

     let tabraw = ui.draggable[0];
     let tab = $( tabraw );

     tabs2.tabs( "refresh" );
    }
      }
    });

 // Close icon: removing the tab on click
 tabs2.on( "click", "span.ui-icon-close", function() {
  var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
  $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
  tabs2.tabs( "refresh" );
 });
    
  
  
  } );
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />



<div id="tabs1">
  <ul class="connectedSortable">
    <li><a href="#tabs-11">tabs-11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-12">tabs-12</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-11">
    <p>tabs-11</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-12">
    <p>tabs-12</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="tabs2">
  <ul class="connectedSortable">
    <li><a href="#tabs-21">tabs-21</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-22">tabs-22</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-21">
    <p>tabs-21</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-22">
    <p>tabs-22</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet, may be you have to modify some code. But it will help you to get your answer.

```js
$(function() {

  var tabs1 = $("#tabs1").tabs();
  tabs1.find(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable({
    axis: "x",
    stop: function() {
      tabs1.tabs("refresh");
    }
  });

  var tabs2 = $("#tabs2").tabs();
  tabs2.find(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable({
    axis: "x",
    stop: function() {
      tabs2.tabs("refresh");
    }
  });

  $('[data-accepts]').each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
      containment: $(this).attr('data-droppable')
    });
  });

  $('[data-droppable]').each(function() {
    $(this).droppable({
      accept: $(this).attr('data-accepts'),
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-active",
        "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
      },
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        //$(event.target).append(ui.draggable);
        var $x = ui.draggable;
        $x.appendTo($(event.target)).css({
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        });
      }
    });
  });


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />


<div id="tabs1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1" data-droppable="#tabs-11" data-accepts="#tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo first.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2" data-droppable="#tabs-22" data-accepts="#tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt first.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3" data-droppable="#tabs-33" data-accepts="#tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis first.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="tabs2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-11">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-22">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-33">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-11" data-droppable="#tabs-11" data-accepts="#tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-22" data-droppable="#tabs-22" data-accepts="#tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-33" data-droppable="#tabs-33" data-accepts="#tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I cannot see any visual improvements. Are you talking only about the code?

Comment: Try to drag tab 1 content to tab 2 content.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my request. I want to be able to drag the (tab+content) from container 1 (up) to container 2 (down) as there will remain 2 tabs up and 4 tabs down.